# After fresh install of OS X my apple watch application work run anymore

Tags: xcode, watchos-2

I did a fresh install for my macbook (after upgrading my HDD to an SSD) but i just realized that my project won't run on device anymore

it work fine on simulator and before changing my hard drive work fine on my iPhone + watch

i have the 3 provising profile (the app, the watch and the extension) but when i try to build i got an error

> Failed to code sign "WizzHeart WatchKit Extension".
>
> None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups, com.apple.developer.healthkit, keychain-access-groups.

and of course the fix issue button dont work [image: the error]

//EDIT: I'm using the free membership so i don't have access to the developer portal

Answer (score 0):

Your private key code signing certificates (which were located in the Keychain) are gone. You'll have to [revoke your old development and distribution certificates](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/) from the Developer portal and generate new ones.

You can generate new ones either right from within Xcode (Preferences -> Accounts; View Details), or via the Developer portal.

**In answer to your comment:**

The Developer portal does not have your private key.

> Because the private key is stored locally on your Mac, protect it as you would an account password. Keep a secure backup of your public-private key pair. If the private key is lost, you’ll have to create an entirely new identity to sign code. ... Private keys are stored only in the keychain and can’t be retrieved if lost.
>
> If you want to code sign your app using another Mac, you export your developer profile on the Mac you used to create your certificates and import it on the other Mac.

See [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) for more details.

Comment: i already did that (from very target i put in the team my account and it downloaded the certificate) but when i try to build the application it just didn't work with that error

Comment: The public key on the Developer Center certificate belongs to a private key which is now lost. That certificate is no longer of any use without your copy of its private key. That's why you have to revoke the old certificates, not download them. I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: i dont have a paid developper membership, just the free so i dont have access to developer portal, and didn't find how to revoke it from Xcode, but i still have the old HDD so i will see if i can extract/export the private keys

Comment: Perhaps someone who has a free membership can explain what you need to do. You should edit that important detail into your question :)